# Native (non-webview) streaming from YouTube?

Tags: cocoa, youtube, video-streaming, youtube-api, web-scraping

I see a lot of applications in the Mac App store, such as [MiniTube](http://flavio.tordini.org/minitube) and [CloudPlay](http://cloudplay.fm), which appear to stream high quality video directly from YouTube, without using any sort of embedded player.

However, I don't see any means of doing this through the documented API. Is their scraping (e.g. http://gitorious.org/minitube/minitube/blobs/master/src/video.cpp) illegal/against the TOS, or merely undocumented and unsupported? Is there a better way of doing it?

(In particular, the so-called "chromeless" iframe player actually has a significant amount of chrome/user interaction, which is more suitable for a website than for a native application.)

EDIT:  I suppose my question is primarily for the official YouTube developer support: is scraping the page for the stream against the TOS? If it is, why are these apps allowed to remain on the app store, and if it isn't, what is the best way of doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any scraping would violate YouTube's TOS.  There are no undocumented APIs available either.  For iOS the best provide option is to use the [YouTube iframe embed](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html), but that will be within a webview.  For Android, YouTube is building a library to do playback without a webview.  Here's a video of the announcement http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WFsx-u-q3Y&feature=player_embedded.  It's not launched yet, but I know they've been working very hard on it and it should be available soon.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Do you have any insight as to why these apps are allowed to continue scraping the site, then?

Comment: I can't comment on what the other sites are doing because I don't know for sure what they're doing.  But like I said before the iframe embed is the only supported way to embed video content on iOS today.

Comment: To give a concrete example, how about this code? http://gitorious.org/minitube/minitube/blobs/master/src/video.cpp

And, are there any plans to support native playback on Mac/iOS in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Never tried this, but according to this discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/QT4FSwl3Rx8) it's against the TOS to access the native streams. They also mention that you are free to access the rstp streams made for mobile devices through the api.

So I think scraping the page is the only way to get the higher quality videos without using an embedded player in your application. If you're okay with lower quality then use the rstp way.

[Another discussion about the same subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700945/youtube-data-api-get-access-to-media-stream-and-play-java).

Comment: Then I suppose my question is primarily for the official YouTube developer support: is scraping the page for the stream against the TOS? If it is, why are these apps allowed to remain on the app store, and if it isn't, what is the best way of doing so?

Comment: If Minitube is respecting Apple's TOS, then Apple have no reason to take them out of the Appstore. I dont see why they would bother enforcing Youtube's TOS. From what I understand, Youtube makes money from advertising, if you have direct access they dont benefit as you are bypassing the advertisments. So I doubt that there is a way to access those streams besides using the embedded player which displays the advertisements.

Comment: From Youtube API TOS in the prohibitions section, article 10 :  **access any portion of any YouTube audiovisual content by any means other than use of a YouTube player or other video player expressly authorized by YouTube**

Comment: Sure, Apple has no reason to enforce YouTube's TOS, but surely YouTube does.

Comment: Yes of course. But Youtube have to take action (not apple). The least they can do is alert Apple about the infraction and see if they will do something about it. Or force the original developers to stop distributing the app (it already exists outside the app store, on windows for example). Also these type of apps are not against the youtube API TOS (because they're not using it :) ), they're against the "Youtube TOS" as found [here](http://www.youtube.com/static?gl=US&template=terms) (See the General Use of the Service section).

Comment: Right, which is why my question is addressed to YouTube.

Comment: sorry got confused, I thought it was for me :).