# Android code to play youtube url repeatedly on button click

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play youtube url play n no of times on button click
I stumbled on the following code on the net:

```
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ux_kvgL570A"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
```

but this code plays youtube url only once,how to modify this code if i want to
play youtube url multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you're using a browser to display the video, but for it, *you need use the Youtube API*.
This thread: [Youtube data API : Get access to media stream and play (JAVA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700945/youtube-data-api-get-access-to-media-stream-and-play-java) can explain you a little more about the youtube implementation on android using a media player.

But to repeat a video, you can add the follow lines:

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.setLooping(true);
    }
});
```

And this is the reference for the YouTube API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications